# RoboGuice inject AnimatorSet

Tags: android, roboguice

First time trying RoboGuice. Till now everything with injecting Views works smoothly.

Since I see in the [tutorial](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/InjectResource) I can inject Resources 
I tried to add an `AnimatorSet` and a get error :

```
 Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't inject null value into class myroboguice.teo.ram.css.myroboguicetest.MainActivity.animatorSet when field is not @Nullable
```

My **code** is :

```
public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {
@InjectView(R.id.textId) TextView textView1;
@InjectView(R.id.buttonId) Button button1;
@InjectView(R.id.buttonId2) Button button2;
@InjectResource(R.animator.button_anim)AnimatorSet animatorSet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textView1.setText("Animator Set");
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

}

public void firstButton(View v) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

public void secondButton(View v) {
    animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.setTarget(button2);
    animatorSet.start();
}

}
```

**LogCat** :

```
 1) Error injecting myroboguice.teo.ram.css.myroboguicetest.MainActivity using roboguice.inject.ResourceListener$ResourceMembersInjector@41694450.
Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't inject null value into class myroboguice.teo.ram.css.myroboguicetest.MainActivity.animatorSet when field is not @Nullable
while locating myroboguice.teo.ram.css.myroboguicetest.MainActivity
1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwProvisionExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:451)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:944)
        at roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:243)
        at roboguice.activity.RoboActivity.onCreate(RoboActivity.java:78)
        at myroboguice.teo.ram.css.myroboguicetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
        ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't inject null value into class myroboguice.teo.ram.css.myroboguicetest.MainActivity.animatorSet when field is not @Nullable
        at roboguice.inject.ResourceListener$ResourceMembersInjector.injectMembers(ResourceListener.java:118)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:120)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:75)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:60)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: What version of Roboguice do you use, 1.1.2 or 2.0b2?

Comment: @Joseph I'm using version 2.0

Comment: Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the source code of TypeListener of Roboguice [here](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/inject/ViewListener.java?r=e2493eb4cd1c23b64eb4af145ede3d2e99edd4f1), and review the code on line 178, I found the exception:

```
if (view == null && Nullable.notNullable(field))
    throw new NullPointerException(String.format("Can't inject null value into %s.%s when field is not @Nullable", field.getDeclaringClass(), field.getName()));
```

On definition class of Nullable:

```
public class Nullable {
    private Nullable() {
    }

    public static boolean notNullable( Field field ) {
        return !isNullable( field );
    }

    public static boolean isNullable(Field field) {
        for( Annotation a : field.getAnnotations() )
            if( Strings.equals("Nullable",a.annotationType().getSimpleName()))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Just annotate your field with

```
@javax.annotation.Nullable
```

annotation and the exception dissapear.

Anyway the animator variable will remain null, because **Animator** resources are not loaded on *injectMembers* method on **Roboguice**:

```
public void injectMembers(T instance) {

        Object value = null;

        try {

            final Resources resources = application.getResources();
            final int id = getId(resources,annotation);
            final Class<?> t = field.getType();

            if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = resources.getString(id);
            } else if (boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(t) || Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = resources.getBoolean(id);
            } else if (ColorStateList.class.isAssignableFrom(t)  ) {
                value = resources.getColorStateList(id);
            } else if (int.class.isAssignableFrom(t) || Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = resources.getInteger(id);
            } else if (Drawable.class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = resources.getDrawable(id);
            } else if (String[].class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = resources.getStringArray(id);
            } else if (int[].class.isAssignableFrom(t) || Integer[].class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = resources.getIntArray(id);
            } else if (Animation.class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
                value = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(application, id);
            } else if (Movie.class.isAssignableFrom(t)  ) {
                value = resources.getMovie(id);
            }

            if (value == null && Nullable.notNullable(field) ) {
                throw new NullPointerException(String.format("Can't inject null value into %s.%s when field is not @Nullable", field.getDeclaringClass(), field
                        .getName()));
            }

            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(instance, value);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can't assign %s value %s to %s field %s", value != null ? value.getClass() : "(null)", value,
                    field.getType(), field.getName()));
        }
    }
```

on **ResourceListener** class on Roboguice.

And I don´t know really why, beacause is just add another condition:

```
else if (Animator.class.isAssignableFrom(t)) {
    value = //read animator from resources
}
```

Unable to use Roboguice is not end of the world. You can load the animator as indicate the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).

Modify your code:

```
    public void secondButton(View v) {
        animatorSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.button_anim);
        animatorSet .setTarget(button2);
        animatorSet .start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and searching through RoboGuice code. I finally did it with the "traditional" old way without injection.

Comment: Thanks to you, I love reviewing the source code and I do not really understand why Roboguice have not implemented an AnimatorSet resource load.